# Update multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
c1 c2 c3
a   1 2000
a   2 2001
a   3 3000
a   4 3001
a   5 3002
```

Step 1: delete rows where c3 = 2000, 2001

```
Delete table where c3 like '2___'
```

Step 2: change 3000 to 2000, 3001 to 2001, 3002 to 2002, and so forth

I'm stuck here. I'd appreciate any pointers or examples.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your C3 column is a string (you don't say):

```
delete MyTable where c3 like '2%'
update MyTable set c3 = '2' + substring(c3, 2, len(c3) - 1) where c3 like '3%'
```

Assuming your C3 column is an integer:

```
delete MyTable where c3 between 2000 and 2999
update MyTable set c3 = c3 - 1000 where c3 between 3000 and 3999
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `DELETE tablename WHERE c3 in (2000, 2001)`

   `DELETE tablename WHERE c3 LIKE '2%'`
2. `UPDATE tablename SET c3 = c3 - 1000`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
DELETE yourtable where c3 in (2000,2001)

UPDATE yourtable
    set C3=C3-1000 
    WHERE  c3>=3000 AND c3<4000
```